# Access dropdown items in Google App Scripts UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script, listbox

I'm using the older depreciated UiApp class in javascript (because I have to) where I have a dropdown list

I need to access the ListBox, and see all the values that it contains.

Is there a way to do this? All the items must be present because there is method that allows you to delete an item by it's index.

I don't want the single value that comes through on the form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly not. The best you can do is store the items using the PropertiesService (or CacheService if the list is over 9kb) when the ListBox is created. Then you can walk that list at will later, and use the ListBox setSelectedIndex() method if needed.

Comment: thanks. great to know i've been on a wild goose chase for 3 hours :p

Comment: You can also store the values as a tag on the listBox itself (stringify the array)

Comment: @Sergeinsas - I was trying to find a way to do this without needing a callback (the PropertiesService & CacheService have been broken for days). But besides using a convoluted trigger and a this[function] call within the callback, I can't see a way. did you come up with anything?

Comment: The _TAG feature is only available in a callback function. That said, I don't see any problem with scriptProperties... what issue are you meeting ?

Comment: @Sergeinsas - [it's on-and-off](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5147), but not as bad as the CacheService in my experience